# Marketing Cloud email attachment via Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, ampscript, fuel-sdk

I was wondering is there a possibility to use Salesforce Service Cloud to send out an email attachment to Marketing Cloud via Salesforce Standard Object "Notes & Attachments"?

Either using AMPScript or API calls?

Example using this url from "Notes & Attachments":
https://c.cs6.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00PN0000002uScw

To push to Marketing Cloud attached as an email an send out.

Comment: That URL isn't publicly accessible. You'd need to make it available the the SFMC servers as they send. In order to understand what you're trying to achieve, could you explain exactly what the use case is, please? Is this attachment specific to the recipient or a generic document sent to all?

Comment: Hi Adam, What im trying to do ideally is to use salesforce to call out SFMC to send out an email (to/cc recipient) via a particular record (e.g oppty). On the same time it also send attachments to it where that attachment is residing  in "note and attachment" from that record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Adam says, one option would be to use SMTP Relay...

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/sending_exacttarget_emails_via_smtp_relay/

On the CRM side of things, you can configure SMTP relay...

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005793&language=en_US

This would route all workflow emails via SFMC from what I read. You'd have to discuss how to send selectively via SFMC with some Salesforce CRM experts (of which I'm definitely not one).

Taking another tack, I can only take you so far with Marketing Cloud. You can trigger an SFMC email either by rolling your own Apex triggers in CRM, or using the relatively new Triggered Send functionality of the V5 connector (the object needs to a have lookup field related to a CRM Lead or Contact)...

https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/sending_emails/triggered_sends/

If the object's not directly related the the Lead or Contact, you'll need to roll your own trigger or the likes to access SFMC's APIs directly.

You can use the AttachFile() AMPScript function within the SFMC email to pull in an attachment from a URL and this URL would need to be passed in as a personalisation string or you could do some Salesforce AMPScript in the email to go search for this value, somehow.

Your challenge would be to make the attachment publicly available so that the AttachFile() can access the file. Using sites in Force.com, here's an example of a thread talking about how to do this...

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F000000099hpIAA

Comment: Thank Macca and Adam !! i try out the suggestion and advices provided by you and Adam. =D

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to send attachments through SFMC utilizing the [AttachFile()](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#AttachFile) AMPScript function.

As [@Macca](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/26543/macca) suggested, where the attachments reside is a key consideration.

Also, It's a per email charge.

Comment: There also is a beta on an SMTP relay that SFMC is offering. It is not exactly pertinent to your question, but may be an alternative solution for you. https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/triggered_emails/sending_exacttarget_emails_via_smtp_relay/

Comment: Adam, your link is not going anywhere. The new one is https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm Thanks for the answer is useful for me.